# Setting up heroku with PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, heroku

I have custom environment variables being set in the php.ini file. I want to override those values in the `user.ini` (to show different things based on this env on heroku) or `fpm_custom.conf` file but I cant seem to get the combination / syntax right.

**In the `php.ini` file**

- env_mode = "Production"

**In the `user.ini` file**

`env_mode = "Development"`

**In the Procfile**

`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -F fpm_custom.conf www/`

**In the `fpm_custom.conf` file**

*??? Here's where I want to set env_more*

I've tried

- `ENV_MODE = "Development"`
- `php_value[ENV_MODE]=Development`
- `php_value ENV_MODE Development`

Any help would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
env[ENV_MODE] = Development
```

Then you can use `getenv('ENV_MODE');` or `$_ENV['ENV_MODE']` in PHP.

That needs to go in your PHP-FPM pool config file (the one in `pool.d` by default).

This sets a PHP environment variable.  `php_value` doesn't set an environment variable, but rather is used to set `php.ini` directives.  So using `php_value ENV_MODE` has no effect.